# Möbius transformation of an area between two lines

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Re}{Re}$I wish to find where all the points in $$\left\{ z:\,\,\,-1<\Re\left(z\right)<0\right\} $$ are mapped to under $$f\left(z\right)=\frac{1}{z+1}$$
I found out $\Re\left(z\right)=0$ goes to a circle with a radius $1/2$ centered at $1/2$ and that $\Re\left(z\right)=-1$ goes to $\Re\left(z\right)=0$ but I have no clue on how proceed, how do I know where all the points **inside** are mapped to?

Comment: There are three options: the left halfplane, the interior of the circle, or the area between the line and the circle. It suffices to map *one* point to decide which is the right one.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know the name of the theorem (if it is indeed called such) that determines that if one point in the said region goes to one of the three, all the other will too?

Comment: Continuous functions map connected sets to connected sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is a Möbius transformation, in particular a continuous automorphism of the extended complex plane $\hat {\Bbb C}$.

$f$ maps the extended line $L_1 = \{  z : \operatorname{Re}(z) = 0 \}\cup \{ \infty \} $ onto the circle $C = \{  z : |z-\frac 12| = \frac 12 \}$, and the extended line $L_2 = \{  z : \operatorname{Re}(z) = -1 \}\cup \{ \infty \} $ onto $L_1$.

Continuous functions map connected sets to connected sets, therefore each connected component of $\hat {\Bbb C} \setminus (L_1 \cup L_2)$ is mapped onto a connected component of $\hat {\Bbb C} \setminus (C \cup L_1)$.

Since $f(-1/2) = 2$, the region between $L_1$ and $L_2$ is mapped onto the intersection of the right half-plane with the exterior of the circle $C$.